# Dynamically created button onClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, being called in `$(document).ready()`:

```
btnHolders.appendChild(_createButton("Note", function(){
    showNote();
}));

var _createButton = function(name, func){
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.id = "btn" + name;
  btn.onclick = func;
  btn.value = name;

  return btn;
};
```

However, when I view the source, I get the following:

`<input type="button" id="btnNote" value="Note">`

Comment: @scrowler, OP told he used document.ready "I have the following code, being called in $(document).ready("

Comment: the onclick will not appear in the 'source'

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: @TarunPai console has no errors.

Comment: You set `onclick` property, not attribute. So it will not appear in HTML.

Comment: How would I make it an attribute? Or does it matter at all?

Comment: @NewAmbition check my answer, it's probably something to do with you calling the `_createButton()` before it was defined.

Comment: @NewAmbition Nope it doesn't matter you can still bind the event you don't actually need the attribute.

Comment: Why was this question edited ? Why remove the jquery tags ?  `$(document).ready()` is jquery. Sometimes users here edit stuff to fit their answer, it's quite lame, also all the answers so far are rubbish.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov rolled it back

Comment: The (initial) code provided contains vanilla `javascript`, you don't need to use any of it if you're using jQuery.

Comment: @TarunPai you pretty much removed the jquery reference before I could even update my code to the actual copy.

Comment: @NewAmbition I removed the jquery tag because the CODE is vanilla js, and I assumed that's what you wanted.

Comment: @TarunPai I understand where you're coming from, but the thing is its called in a JQuery function. If it was an error in `$(document).ready` then it will boil down to a JQuery error. Plus, it will help anyone else stuck on this using JQuery.

Comment: @NewAmbition added the jquery tag back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit as you were calling a function that wasn't defined before. Also why not use jQuery to shorten your code since you already included it?

```
var btnHolders = $('#btnHolders');

_createButton("Note", showNote);

function _createButton(name, func){
  var btn = $('<input/>').attr({
      'type': 'button',
      'id': 'btn' + name,
      'value': name
  }).bind('click', func);

  btnHolders.append(btn);
};

function showNote() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8HALs/1/)

Comment: You're calling `_createButton` before it was defined, and your demo is not working.

Comment: @TarunPai You can call a function the way I did it since the function wasn't assigned to a `var`iable like the OP did. Please first think before downvoting. Also the demo is working fine for me.

Comment: Undo-ed the downvote. There's a problem with the question imho. It's a mix of vanilla js and jquery.

Comment: @TarunPai what's the issue with mixing Vanilla JS with JQuery, besides personal preference?

Comment: @NewAmbition it gives you cleaner code imo. In your case, with jqueyr you can have *the* click handler written separately, and you'll avoid a lot of mess like `btn.onclick` since you're pre-attaching the click handler. There's a bigger picture to it. Just cleaner code imo

Comment: @TarunPai so it is personal preference? Besides the ONE JQuery loading command, everything else is vanilla. I don't see how that mix will cause *a lot of mess*.

Comment: @NewAmbition in this case it probably won't. You're loading up one extra file (even though it's small) for one line of code.

Comment: @TarunPai The only reason I'm using this is because I'm currently fixing a lot of code. I try avoid using JQuery, but the rest of the page does. So, in the interim, I'm using one JQuery command purely because its there for me to use. I really don't think you should get your personal preferences mixed up in the question. You really led this off-topic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47649/discussion-between-tarun-pai-and-newambition)

Comment: @TarunPai Sorry, but I'm with NewAmbition on this one, nothing wrong with it. At all.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do in javascript, refer this...

Refer the following fiddle...
[fiddle1] : http://jsfiddle.net/pfCdd/

```
function myFunction(){
    var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t=document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onclick = myfunc;
}
myFunction();
function myfunc(){
    alert("hai");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use live click on the button:

```
$("#btnNote").click(function(){    
   alert('i am here ');
})
```

Comment: Have you read the below answers that now have - score ? BTW: `live` has been deprecated for `on`